# jQuery JIRA Post not working in IE/FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to post data to JIRA and it seems to only work in Chrome. Does not work in IE/FF. Please Help. I think this has something to do with the ajax call setup. Not sure what I need to get this to work.

```js
       $('#new_request > footer > input').bind('click', function(e) {
    
        var subjects = $("#request_subject").val();
        var descriptions = $("#request_description").val();
        var attachments = $(".upload-link").attr('href');
        var cust1 = $("#request_custom_fields_27736417").val();
        var cust2 = $("#request_custom_fields_27745068").val();
        var cust3 = $("#request_custom_fields_27736427").val();
        var cust4 = $("#request_custom_fields_27745078").val();
        var cust5 = $("#request_custom_fields_27736437").val();
        var cust6 = $("#request_custom_fields_27638038").val();
        var cust7 = $("#request_custom_fields_27638118").val();
        var cust8 = $("#request_custom_fields_27632077").val();
        var cust9 = $("#request_custom_fields_27632087").val();
            
        if (subjects !== null || descriptions !== null){
          
                 function CreateJIRATicket(summary,description, custom1,custom2,custom3,custom4,custom5,custom6,custom7,custom8,custom9,custom10 ) {
 
            var JIRAusername = "YouruserName";
            var JIRApassword = "YourPassword";
          
 
          
            var jsondata = {"fields": 
         { "project":{ "key": "ZDI"},
         "summary": summary,
         "description":description,
        "issuetype": {"name": "Story" }, 
       "customfield_11200" : custom1, 
       "customfield_11201" : custom2,
       "customfield_11202" : custom3,  
       "customfield_11203" : custom4,  
       "customfield_11204" : custom5,  
       "customfield_11205" : custom6,  
       "customfield_11206" : custom7, 
       "customfield_11207" : custom8, 
       "customfield_11208" : custom9,
       "customfield_11209" : custom10
         } 
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                
                crossDomain: true,
                contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                username: JIRAusername,
                password: JIRApassword,
                data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
                url: "https://jira.yourdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue",
                xhrFields: {
                    "withCredentials": true
                },
             
                success: function (ticket){
                    console.log('Page saved!', ticket); 
                },
                error : function(xhr, errorText){
                    console.log('Error '+ xhr.responseText);
                }
   
   
   
            })//end ajax post JIRA 
 
        }
     
 


    }
    



          
          
            CreateJIRATicket(subjects, descriptions, cust1, cust2, cust3, cust4, cust5, cust6, cust7, cust8, cust9, attachments);
    

        
      });
  
  
  
    }
```

Comment: What't the error you get? That crossDomain switch looks suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Code reorganized: function **CreateJIRATicket** taking out of the IF structure, and changed **contentType** to use the default (why "application/json" ?). Try this:

```
function CreateJIRATicket(summary,description, custom1,custom2,custom3,custom4,custom5,custom6,custom7,custom8,custom9,custom10) {
    var JIRAusername = "YouruserName";
    var JIRApassword = "YourPassword";
    var jsondata = {"fields": 
        { "project":{ "key": "ZDI"},
        "summary": summary,
        "description":description,
        "issuetype": {"name": "Story" }, 
        "customfield_11200" : custom1, 
        "customfield_11201" : custom2,
        "customfield_11202" : custom3,  
        "customfield_11203" : custom4,  
        "customfield_11204" : custom5,  
        "customfield_11205" : custom6,  
        "customfield_11206" : custom7, 
        "customfield_11207" : custom8, 
        "customfield_11208" : custom9,
        "customfield_11209" : custom10}
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        crossDomain: true,
        contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        username: JIRAusername,
        password: JIRApassword,
        data: JSON.stringify(jsondata),
        url: "https://jira.yourdomain.com/rest/api/2/issue",
        xhrFields: {"withCredentials": true},
        success: function (ticket){console.log('Page saved!', ticket);},
        error : function(xhr, errorText){console.log('Error '+ xhr.responseText);}
    })//end ajax post JIRA 
}

$('#new_request > footer > input').bind('click', function(e) {
    var subjects = $("#request_subject").val();
    var descriptions = $("#request_description").val();

    if (subjects !== null || descriptions !== null){
        var attachments = $(".upload-link").attr('href');
        var cust1 = $("#request_custom_fields_27736417").val();
        var cust2 = $("#request_custom_fields_27745068").val();
        var cust3 = $("#request_custom_fields_27736427").val();
        var cust4 = $("#request_custom_fields_27745078").val();
        var cust5 = $("#request_custom_fields_27736437").val();
        var cust6 = $("#request_custom_fields_27638038").val();
        var cust7 = $("#request_custom_fields_27638118").val();
        var cust8 = $("#request_custom_fields_27632077").val();
        var cust9 = $("#request_custom_fields_27632087").val();
        CreateJIRATicket(subjects, descriptions, cust1, cust2, cust3, cust4, cust5, cust6, cust7, cust8, cust9, attachments);
    }
});
```